# Is it possible to programmatically call, access, or get results from the Unity Dash?

Tags: unity-dash, application-development, lenses, unity

### Background

After eyeing Unity's notification APIs for the past few releases, I've developed an itch to write a feed reader that syndicates new arrivals in the Messaging Menu...

[image: Messaging menu]

... and provides search in the dash.

[image: Dash image]

It would be nice to open the dash straight from the messaging menu, directly to the feed lens searching a selected term. Look at the pictures above to see what I mean.

### Question

Essentially, is there a Unity API to:

1. Summon the dash?
2. Set the dash's active lens?
3. Set the dash's search term?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can certainly add search data sources (we call them "scopes") for the Dash, and lenses through which to view them. Scopes can also add results to existing lenses.

I don't know that there is an API today to invoke the dash on a particular lens programatically, but it's a very good idea that such an API exist. I like the example you give of having an indicator which has a menu item that leads to a lens very much.

So, [please file a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug), feel free to copy this comment in for support, and patches welcome.

---

Addendum: [bug #896402](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/896402) has been filed.

Comment: [Here is the bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/896402).

Answer (score 1):

It should be possible. You can have a look at the 'documentation' [here (python)](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-11.10/python/Unity-4.0.html) or [here](http://developer.ubuntu.com/api/ubuntu-11.10/c/Unity-4.0.html). Maybe you should [file a bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity) that the documentation is less then incomplete.